# most efficient way to use reflection on a js object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the most efficient way to use reflection on a js object?  Here's an example data structure:

```
  var data = {
    NortheastRegion:
    {
        RegionName: 'Northeast',    
        SomeGeneralRegionInfo: 'Info1'
    }
    SoutheastRegion:
    {
        RegionName: 'Southeast',    
        SomeGeneralRegionInfo: 'Info2'      
    }
  }
```

Let's say I'd like to use a reflection style similar to this:

```
var regionName = 'SoutheastRegion';
var region = data[regionName];
var info = region.SomeGeneralRegionInfo;
```

What would be the most efficient way to do something like this?

Comment: 1. `Here's an example data structure` this is not syntactically correct 2. I don't think what you call reflection is really reflection. 3. What do you mean by "efficient"? 4. Why do you think your proposed way of doing this is "inefficient"?

Comment: FYI, the syntax error is a missing comma before `SoutheastRegion`.

Comment: What's inefficient about what you've already got? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What you're calling reflection is just dynamically accessing properties. Reflection means asking the system for information about itself, such like using `Object.keys(data)`.